# is the overhead of PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK mutex type significant over PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL types?

Tags: pthreads, mutex

Am trying to understand if the overhead caused by mutex checks for mutex attribute type PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK is significant over the PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL type. I mean, are there any benchmark results or any data available to make this decision in our implementation.

Any references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Requests for (recommendations for) offsite resources are off topic here.

Comment: Not just references, if anyone has already done the research, they can share the view as well.